# Mysql Stored Procedure not returning a INT out parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, store

Below is my stored procedure.

It works fine but my problem is I can't get the output parameter as `INT`.

The part where I'm having problem is the assignment of the out parameter `@Number2` from `@n` variable value.

```
SET Number2 = @n;
```

I'd appreciate any help. I actually just learned mysql recently.

Thanks.

Here's the Stored Procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`tUser`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP`(OUT Number2 INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE Number2 INT(11);
DECLARE n INT(11);

SET @t = CONCAT('SELECT
                 COUNT(allfiles)
                 FROM
                 t_contents 
                 WHERE sID_contents > 0 
                 INTO @n;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @t;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT @n;

SET Number2 = @n;

END
```

Comment: You have 2 variables with the same name `Number2` which is wrong. Remove `DECLARE Number2 INT(11);`/ You do not use variable `n`. Remove `DECLARE n INT(11);`.

Comment: @Akina thanks a lot for this help!